# Calloc causes segmantation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, calloc

I am trying to add a set a string in my struct array's struct. I coded this in Macos using gcc (not clang) and works fine but when i import my code to Windows this calloc causes segmantation fault.

```
index = varlist.var_count;
varlist.var_count++;
varlist.vars = (Var *)realloc(varlist.vars, sizeof(Var) * varlist.var_count);
varlist.vars[index].called = (char *)calloc(1, sizeof(char) * strlen(var.called));
strcpy(varlist.vars[index].called, var.called);
```

this is my structs definitation

```
struct Var
{
    int id;
    char * called;
    void * ptr;
    int type;
};
typedef struct Var Var;

struct Varlist
{
    int var_count;
    Var * vars;
};
typedef struct Varlist Varlist;
```

Comment: I'm gonna guess you aren't leaving enough room for a null terminator.

Comment: `sizeof(char) * strlen(var.called)` should be `sizeof(char) * (1+strlen(var.called))`

Comment: @IłyaBursov `sizeof(char)` is redundant because it's defined to be always 1.  It's better to write `strlen(var.called) + 1`, because that extra byte is needed at the end; meaning matters.

Comment: As an aside, the first argument of `calloc` should be the number of elements of the array you are allocating, and the second argument should be the size of an element of the array.

Comment: interesting it works fine, i thought var.called have already null terminator. Thanks

Comment: `var.called` may have a null terminator, but that terminator is not included in the value returned from `strlen`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons oh right i didnt notice that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic code is this code snippet

```
varlist.vars[index].called = (char *)calloc(1, sizeof(char) * strlen(var.called));
strcpy(varlist.vars[index].called, var.called);
```

You are using functions designed to deal with strings (like `strlen` and `strcpy`) but the allocated character arrays do not contain strings because they do not reserve space for the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

You have to write at least like

```
varlist.vars[index].called = calloc( strlen(var.called) + 1, sizeof(char) );
```

wherein `var.called` also must contain a string.

So check also the code where the string pointed to by the pointer `var.called` is formed.